# Get a property from object

Tags: c#, properties

I have a object that some of the properties can be encrypted (if there is information for it on the DB) or empty (if there is no information on the DB for it)

For example, for the email, I'm doing it like this;

```
public string Email
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email))
            return "";
        else
            return Crypto.Decrypt(this.Email, GlobalVars.VALID_KEY);
    }
    set
    {
        this.Email = value;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish by this is, when the value is set it will be a empty string or a encrypted string, and when I need the property it will pass me the empty string or the decrypt string

On debug mode, I did put a pointbreak to check something on the object and when the VS was evaluating the object I got this error:

> The target process exited with code -2147023895 while evaluating the function ....Email.get

any advices for this ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have an infinitely recursive call in the get and the set.

Comment: Ty, after putting the set/get into a variable on the object it self the problem did disapear :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `Email` in `get`, that creates an infinity loop.

Try this :

```
private string _email;
public string Email
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_email))
            return "";
        else
            return Crypto.Decrypt(_email, GlobalVars.VALID_KEY);
    }
    set
    {
        _email = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually solved my problem, putting code like the answer with a little change, `this._email = value`
Antoine V edit the answer with this change to put it as a valid answer for the problem I did have

Comment: @Camadas it is not standard naming convention to use `this.` in front of variables in C# (at least not in most cases). If you are using Visual Studio, it will also notify you of this.

Comment: @Noceo thanks for the advice, but yes using the VS and I don't get a notify for it.

Comment: @Noceo It´s pure fine to add a (redundant) `this` in front. VS won´t notify, but ReSharper may.

Comment: My bad. Its not a warning, but a "Name can be simplified." suggestion (VS2017). The point remains the same though :-).